# Redmine: Change Project Identifier?

Tags: redmine

Is there a way to change the `identifier` of a project, without directly editing the database?

There is no obvious option to change it in the WebUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this has been an "issue" for a while:
https://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/2918?r=48986

Project identifiers are clearly not meant to be modified. It appears that the expectation is that one should delete a project and re-create it with the new identifier. Since this is unacceptable to me, I found a way around it.

The web interface does not allow for changing the identifier and there are a few roadblocks in the Project class itself that prevents one from just opening a console and running something like this (which, as a Rails developer, I would expect to be able to do):

```ruby
p = Project.find_by(identifier: 'old-identifier')
p.identifier = 'new-identifier'
p.save
```

However, I have found that one can do this from a production console:

```ruby
p = Project.where(identifier: 'old-identifier').first
p.instance_eval { self['identifier'] = 'new-identifier' }
p.save
```

Note: To access a "production console"...

> `cd` into [R]edmine install directory, then run `RAILS_ENV=production rails console`

(Thanks, [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73878/dave))

Comment: I have this exact problem, an old project was renamed and I'd really like to keep existing project history but change the identifier to the new project name. I am not a Ruby/Rails/Redmine expert, how does one open a production console? I have seen some references to "script/console production" but there is no "console" file in my Redmine 3.4.6 install's script folder.

Comment: I figured it out: cd into redmine install directory, then run `RAILS_ENV=production rails console`. This worked great for me. Thanks for posting.